# Scoped CSS for only a specific component in Svelte-Sapper

Tags: css, svelte, sapper

Here is my file structure in sapper a project (only relevant files):

```
src/
    -routes/
        -_layout.svelte
        -index.svelte
        -other.svelte
    -styles/
        -index.css
        -other.css
```

I import the css files by this method:

```
<script>
  import '../styles/index.css'
</script>
```

I use `header` selector in both css files. When I route from index to other page the index.css's header styles also applied in the other.svelte page. But if I refresh in `/other` page in my browser it looks okay.

I want to scope my styles in a specific page. How to restrict my styles for other pages?

Here is my dependencies from package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "polka": "next",
    "sirv": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sapper": "^0.28.0",
    "svelte": "^3.17.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^14.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^8.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-url": "^5.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^6.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to define route-specific styles is to write your css directly in the `<style></style>` section of your Sapper route files (in your case, `index.svelte` and `other.svelte`).

These styles will have precedence over the `global.css` stylesheet which is loaded from `template.html` (if you use the Sapper template app).

Comment: I have already tried this approach but happened the same things